# "I don't know how's Jack": the word order

Tags: word-order

[This jazz chant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iHfxfh6lyQ) is called "I don't know how's Jack". Why isn't the word order in the title like this "...how Jack is"?

Comment: In the audio, is she saying "_I don't know_"? Sounds like something else.

Comment: The audio is ok, but what about the title?

Comment: "I don't know *how Jack is*" is normal word order for the clause. I don't know where it is.  I don't know when they left.  I don't know who took it. I don't know what it is. I don't know why they took it.

Comment: Is there a mistake, then?

Comment: "I don't know how's Jack" is definitely not standard and looks like a mistake.  Maybe it was supposed to be two separate sentences?  "I don't know.  How's Jack?"